# how to define model of JSON.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm a little bit of confused about when I see the JSON visualizer how exactly I have to define the model that JSON deserializes correctly;
for example:
[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA2I8.png)

Text:

> {"questions":[{"QID":"NEW0","Context":"از چه سنی مبتلا به دیابت
> شدید؟"},{"QID":"8","Context":"قند خون سه ساعت بعد از وعده غذایی
> (میانگین قند خونی که در دو روز اخیر اندازه گرفتید)"}]}

I had an array of Javascript Classe (Questions which is made of Question) now I sent it to the controller side and do not have any idea how I have to deserialize it. I've tested these things and none of them worked.

Wrong ones: (Jsonstring is the JSON object in action's arguments)

```
 var QustionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int,Ques>>(jsonstring);

 var QustionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Ques>>(jsonstring);

 var QustionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<List<Ques>>(jsonstring);

 var QustionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<Ques>(jsonstring);
```

Here is Ques:

```
public class Ques
{
  public string QID { get; set; }
  public string Context{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just use a tool, e.g. https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: tnx a lot. It runs my job but I want to know what's really happening in the backside of json deserialization. Do you know any reference to study this subject?

Comment: Well what happens is JSON is a structured format with a couple of tokens (`{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `:`, `"` and `,`). The Json.Net library takes the string/stream/byte array and parses the tokens, roughly going like so: 'oh, we encounter `{` -> means we are starting an object, oh we encounter `[` -> means we are starting an array, oh we encounter `"` -> means it's a string-like data. It then takes your POCO type and tries to match keys based on some conventions and assign values.

Comment: your json object is an array of `Ques`, hence `jsonConvert.DesiralizeObject<List<Ques>>(jsonString);` should work!

Comment: I just tested that site and it didn't work QuestionList is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top level property in your JSON string is "questions", which is an array of objects, therefore you need a top level class to hold that property. eg

```
    public class Root
    {
        public Question[] Questions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public string QID { get; set; }
        public string Context { get; set; }
    }
```

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```